# How do I represent multiple values as one unique state in reinforcement-learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm currently teaching myself reinforcement-learning with Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction by Sutton & Barto.
I'm a little bit confused, because you often have to combine multiple values into one unique state which can then be used for reinforcement-learning. How do I achieve this? Is there some kind of hashing-algorithm?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Some *types* for representing multiple values are

1. A tuple of values $(x, y, z)$ is an arbitrary ordered collection of variables
2. A set of values $\{x, y, z\}$ is unordered, and with all elements of the same type
3. You can also define fancier [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) to specify the exact construct that you want.

Anyway, mathematicians are perfectly happy with saying "i've combined my two values into one by putting them into a tuple", but you might also be interested in the more practical question of "how can I use my values as an index in hash-table", which might be useful for tabular Q-learning, and for that you do need your values to be hashable.

I imagine you can hash a tuple by hashing all the elements, then concatenate them and hash the result. You can extend this to sets by lexicographically sorting the hashes of the elements before concatenating and hashing the result.

Comment: Thank you a lot!